# Jquery how to get value input from last tr only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

```
                <tr id="subpage_title1">
                            <td class="order minus">1</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkF[]" checked="" value=""> Front (A)</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkB[]" value=""> Back (C)</td>            
                            <td><input id="hfloor" class="sum" name="hfloor[]" type="number" min="100" max="5000" step="1" value="3000"></td>
                            <td></td>
                </tr><tr id="subpage_title2">
                            <td class="order ">2</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkF[]" checked="" value=""> Front (A)</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkB[]" value=""> Back (C)</td>            
                            <td><input id="hfloor" class="sum" name="hfloor[]" type="number" min="100" max="5000" step="2" value="3000"></td>
                            <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="subpage_title3" style="display: table-row;">
                            <td class="order">3</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkF[]" checked="" value=""> Front (A)</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkB[]" value=""> Back (C)</td>
                            <td><input id="hfloor"  class="sum"  name="hfloor[]" type="number" min="100" max="5000" step="3" value="3000"></td>
                            <td><a class="btn-remove-tr btn btn-small">Delete Floor</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="subpage_title4" style="display: table-row;">
                        <td class="order">4</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkF[]" checked="" value=""> Front (A)</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkB[]" value=""> Back (C)</td>
                        <td><input id="hfloor"  class="sum"  name="hfloor[]" type="number" min="100" max="5000" step="4" value="2000"></td>
                        <td><a class="btn-remove-tr btn btn-small">Delete Floor</a></td>
                </tr>
```

I'm tired to get value  input class="sum" from last  tr only, please  some one help me!!

if i delete one row i must get the last value and if i add another row i must get  the last value

Comment: You can't have more than one `hfloor` id. ids are meant to be unique.

Comment: Unless there are other `.sum` element on the page, just doing `$('.sum').last()` should do it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$( "tr:last td input.sum" )
```

Comment: would not work, the input has the 'sum' class not the td

Answer (score 1):

The html:

```
   <table>
        <tr id="subpage_title1">
                    <td class="order minus">1</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkF[]" checked="" value=""> Front (A)</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkB[]" value=""> Back (C)</td>            
                    <td><input id="hfloor" class="sum" name="hfloor[]" type="number" min="100" max="5000" step="1" value="3000"></td>
                    <td></td>
        </tr><tr id="subpage_title2">
                    <td class="order ">2</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkF[]" checked="" value=""> Front (A)</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkB[]" value=""> Back (C)</td>            
                    <td><input id="hfloor" class="sum" name="hfloor[]" type="number" min="100" max="5000" step="2" value="3000"></td>
                    <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="subpage_title3" style="display: table-row;">
                    <td class="order">3</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkF[]" checked="" value=""> Front (A)</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkB[]" value=""> Back (C)</td>
                    <td><input id="hfloor"  class="sum"  name="hfloor[]" type="number" min="100" max="5000" step="3" value="3000"></td>
                    <td><a class="btn-remove-tr btn btn-small">Delete Floor</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="subpage_title4" style="display: table-row;">
                <td class="order">4</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkF[]" checked="" value=""> Front (A)</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkB[]" value=""> Back (C)</td>
                <td><input id="hfloor"  class="sum"  name="hfloor[]" type="number" min="100" max="5000" step="4" value="2000"></td>
                <td><a class="btn-remove-tr btn btn-small">Delete Floor</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

script:

```
$(function(){
var value = $( "tr:last td input.sum" ).val()
console.log(value)
})
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sbtLkm81/5/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log($('table tr:last td input.sum').val())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr id="subpage_title1">
                            <td class="order minus">1</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkF[]" checked="" value=""> Front (A)</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkB[]" value=""> Back (C)</td>            
                            <td><input id="hfloor" class="sum" name="hfloor[]" type="number" min="100" max="5000" step="1" value="3000"></td>
                            <td></td>
                </tr><tr id="subpage_title2">
                            <td class="order ">2</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkF[]" checked="" value=""> Front (A)</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkB[]" value=""> Back (C)</td>            
                            <td><input id="hfloor" class="sum" name="hfloor[]" type="number" min="100" max="5000" step="2" value="3000"></td>
                            <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="subpage_title3" style="display: table-row;">
                            <td class="order">3</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkF[]" checked="" value=""> Front (A)</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkB[]" value=""> Back (C)</td>
                            <td><input id="hfloor"  class="sum"  name="hfloor[]" type="number" min="100" max="5000" step="3" value="3000"></td>
                            <td><a class="btn-remove-tr btn btn-small">Delete Floor</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="subpage_title4" style="display: table-row;">
                        <td class="order">4</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkF[]" checked="" value=""> Front (A)</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkB[]" value=""> Back (C)</td>
                        <td><input id="hfloor"  class="sum"  name="hfloor[]" type="number" min="100" max="5000" step="4" value="2000"></td>
                        <td><a class="btn-remove-tr btn btn-small">Delete Floor</a></td>
                </tr>
                
                <table>
```

try this.

Comment: Bad selectors. Just this `$('table tr:last td input.sum').val()` would be fine